# FaultException and Details

Tags: wcf

I am working on WCF Services from Couple of Days. I had a written a service with an Exception as

```
public String Login(string Vendorname, string VendorAccessCode)
    {        
        try
        {
        if()
        {
        }
        else
        {
            UserIdentityToken = string.Empty;
            this.ErrorMessage = "Authentication failed. Please contact administrator";
            throw new FaultException(this.ErrorMessage);
        }

        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
           logger.Error(ex.Message); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.Message); 
        }

        return UserIdentityToken;
    }
```

After this i am handling the exceptions in client side in a Messgae Inspector as

```
      public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
     {


    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        if (reply.IsFault)
        {

            MessageFault fault = MessageFault.CreateFault(new FaultCode("Receiver"), new FaultReason(reply.ToString()));
            throw new FaultException(fault);
        }
    }
   }
```

I am handling my Client Side Code as

```
            try
            {                                objVendorServiceClient.Login(txtuserName.Text.Trim(),
txtAccessCode.Text.Trim());               
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {                
                lblAuthenticationMessage.Text = ex.Message;                
                throw ex;
            }
```

But when ever the authentication fails in Service, the Reply.IsFault is returning false only. could any one explain me what is reply.Isfault and how exactly it is useful to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**Message.IsFault Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.isfault.aspx):
>
> Gets a value that indicates whether this message generates any SOAP faults.

You say:

> when ever the authentication fails in Service, the Reply.IsFault is returning false

That is because you catch the fault yourself, log it, and then return an empty string. You'll have to throw the FaultException in order for WCF to catch it and create a SOAP fault from it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Suggestion. But When i am trying to retrieve the Exception in Message Inspector, i am retrieving the MessageFault in MessageInspector as mentioned in my question. This is giving me the raw Soap Format. Can i get an exact error message here ?

Comment: @Bhuvan I would like to see more code for the Message Inspector and can you also show what SOAP message you receive, for example using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

Comment: Hi i edited my Question, I attached the Message Inspector and the SOAP Value which i received in exception.

Comment: i am retrieveing the soap based error message from the exception stirng